# Unreasonable reviewer request (grant re-submission strategy)

Tags: funding, rejection

For a grant proposal for my home country's key funding agency (e.g., NIH equivalent), I received a rejection.

Unfortunately, the review panel picked up predominantly the comments of one of the three reviewers stating that there is a putatively better method available to address a key aspect of the research question.

The technical suggestion is possibly true. However, there are zero groups within my country that apply this highly experimental technique. The two to three European groups applying this technique only work with healthy volunteers for physiology studies (i.e., no patient examinations).

*As a putative example, think of some 'fancy' MRI device that is used for experimental patient imaging in only two to three centers in the world.*

Considering that a brief point-by-point response is required for re-submission:

1. Would you just add a collaborator in the closest neighbor country
   plus patient travel costs to the grant (drastically inflating the
   costs)?
2. Would you consider objecting to the review panel
   highlighting the impracticalities (i.e., requiring study patients
   to travel internationally)?

Comment: I don't know if there are any particulars to your situation (e.g., EU membership) that would make it easier, but I can't even fathom writing an IRB application to my institution that would involve patients traveling to another country.

Comment: Kind of cut myself off at the question part of the previous comment...I meant to ask: is there a reason you think this is feasible? That is, is this (shipping patients to the closest neighbor country) something you're familiar with doing or other people doing?

Comment: I gather you are re-submitting to the same funding agency? Did they actively encourage to do this? Do you have any idea about the chances of having a modified resubmission with a point-by-point response accepted? When this kind of thing happened to me I was told by knowledgeable people within my institution that it's rather hopeless but it's still better to file a response because this makes a good impression in case you later apply for something else. With that information I didn't lose much sleep over how to do it. But of course your situation/funding body may be different.

Comment: @BryanKrause: I work in the rare disease space. About 60% of our patients come from outside of my country and are also seen by other doctors elsewhere. A signficiant fraction of them (~50 %) would be will to go somewhere else in addition (if the purpose is explained to them).

Comment: @BryanKrause: A 'joint' IRB submission would be difficult (especially since the device is not CE-marked and requires special, country-dependent regulations). It would be two separate studies (with data-sharing agreements in place), and patients would be encouraged to participate in both.

Comment: @ChristianHennig: The was no 'specific invitation to resubmit' in the text. However, the letter states explicitly that the commission acknowledges the high relevance and importance to the field (as stated by the three reviewers).

Comment: @William I see, well, I think you likely need more specific advice than is typically available on this site. Option 1 seems like it's only going to help you if you're able to convince the granting org that this is all reasonable, like if you can point to previous studies where you or your collaborators have done something similar, or add personnel who have experience doing these sorts of multi-country clinical trials. Option 2 is kind of the opposite: if Option 1 is feasible, then it seems not very convincing that you could also argue it's impractical. It seems to depend on your situation.

Comment: In general, I'd recommend favoring emphasizing the benefits of your proposal over downplaying the drawbacks of not being able to do something else. Funding orgs want to fund exciting stuff, not fund what's merely the best you can manage.

Comment: Peer review actually worked here: The reviewers picked up on a substantial flaw of the study, and pointed it out. They did not know that you considered the idea (or maybe you didn't -- that doesn't actually matter here) and discarded it as impractical: But that's a problem in the proposal. It is ok to state in a proposal that there is a specific method around, but that it is not practical for you to use it because of X, Y, and Z. If well explained, reviewers typically accept these sorts of reasons, but it's *your* job to make the case for or against something.

Comment: Thank you to @BryanKrause: The 'want to fund exciting stuff' part makes sense to me, and I will go for the 'adding an international collaborator' variant. (Of course, the more difficult logistics might provide an 'attack surface' for the next reviewer.)

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Thank you for your thoughtful comments! Yes and no. The peer review worked (reviewer 2 comments were critical, but technically fine), and my proposal could have anticipated/justified such comments. Nevertheless, the funding agency panel somewhat failed. At least in my field, there is always somewhere in the world a better experimental imaging device for some lesion subtype. Even if I accommodate the request of reviewer 2, a new reviewer can easily come up and mention 'some novel technique used in 3 patients in Tokyo'.  Of course, unlike mice, patients can't be 'shipped' ...

Comment: @William So make that point: "We will image patients using [method X]. While there are better techniques available today, we chose [method X] because it is locally available at our institution and because the resolution we can get from this method is sufficient for our purposes."